# What is the equivalent of @Context annotation from JAX-RS in Spring to inject HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In JAX-RS resource classes we can use

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

to be able to access details from the HTTP request.

What is the equivalent of the above line in Spring Boot? I don't want to add `HttpServletRequest` as argument in each method of my REST controller class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`@Autowired`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)?

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```